# proxy not serving for get request : http-proxy-middleware

Tags: node.js, reactjs, reverse-proxy, http-proxy-middleware

I am using http-proxy-middleware for reverse proxying the application in order to avoid CORS during development.

Following is the setup for http-proxy-middleware that is being used. I am getting the response for each method except **GET**.

Setup :

Path: **server/index.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import webpackMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';
import webpackHotMiddleware from 'webpack-hot-middleware';
import webpackConfig from '../webpack.config.dev';
let proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');
let app = express();
const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);
app.use(webpackMiddleware(compiler, {
hot: true,
noInfo: true
}));
app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './index.html'));
});
let options = {
target: 'https://example.com',
changeOrigin: true,
logLevel:'debug',
ws: true,
onProxyReq: function(proxyReq, req, res) {        
    //  log the req
    console.log('RAW REQUEST from the target', JSON.stringify(req.headers, true, 2));
},
onProxyRes: function (proxyRes, req, res) {

    //  log the response
    console.log('RAW Response from the target', JSON.stringify(proxyRes.headers, true, 2));
}
};
app.use(['/front_end_api/**'], proxy(options));
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Running on localhost'));
```

**Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong here.**

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your proxy ahead of `webpack-dev-middleware`.
There is an issue with `http-proxy-middleware` which might be related to what you are seeing.
https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/issues/199